# Avoid validation of @Size annotation in JPA

Tags: validation, jsf, jpa

I have a JPA entity with the following attribute:

```
public class Person implements Serializabe {
...
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String name;
...
```

And it's view:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name: "/>           
<h:inputText id="name"
             value="#{personBean.person.name}"
             validator="#{personValidator.validate}"/>
<rich:message for="name"/>
```

The `personValidator` checks if 0 < name.length < 45 and if it already exists in the database; it works fine. When I try do add an empty name, or bigger than 45 chars, I get my correct validator message but in the Glassfish output is shown:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=contentForm:name[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(size must be between 1 and 45), detail=(size must be between 1 and 45)]
```

I have tried adding `<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>` to my persistence.xml but no effect. How do I avoid this `@Size`annotation validation?

Comment: redundancy between `@Column(nullable=false)` and `@NotNull` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message you're seeing is because a faces message (likely originating from a validator) has been emitted, but likely has not been displayed.

In this case, the `@Size` annotation is from Bean Validation and is processed by both JPA and JSF.

Unless you manually generated the message from your backing bean (by e.g. putting a try/catch around your business logic) this one is really coming from JSF and disabling anything in JPA's `persistence.xml` won't make a difference.

You can disable the JSF validation by nesting an `f:validateBean` tag inside your input components and setting the `disabled` attribute to true. See [Temoporarily suppress beanvalidation with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332713/temoporarily-suppress-beanvalidation-with-jsf)

Comment: I have chosen this one as the correct answer because of the complete explanation, but @Arjan Tijms the `disabled` attribute must be edited to `true` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the validation for the specific input by adding a `validateBean` tag:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name: "/>           
<h:inputText id="name"
             value="#{personBean.person.name}"
             validator="#{personValidator.validate}">
    <f:validateBean disabled="true"/>
</h:inputText>
<rich:message for="name"/>
```